# Hadoop using Flume to pull twitter tweets

Tags: hadoop, twitter, flume

I am getting a sink error when I try to fetch twitter tweets. I added the Twitter API configurations and created a directory in HDFS. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I am using Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.2.1

```
ERROR flume.SinkRunner: Unable to deliver event. 
ERROR hdfs.HDFSEventSink: process failed
```

Exception follows.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is supposed to be overridden by subclasses.
```

flume.conf

```html
# Naming the components on the current agent. 
TwitterAgent.sources = twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = memoryChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS
  
# Describing/Configuring the source 
TwitterAgent.sources.twitter.type = org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.twitter.consumerKey = Xxx
TwitterAgent.sources.twitter.consumerSecret = Xxx 
TwitterAgent.sources.twitter.accessToken = Xxx
TwitterAgent.sources.twitter.accessTokenSecret = Xxx
TwitterAgent.sources.twitter.maxBatchDurationMillis = 200 
TwitterAgent.sources.twitter.channels = memoryChannel
TwitterAgent.sources.twitter.keywords = lsu
  
TwitterAgent.channels.memoryChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.memoryChannel.capacity = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.memoryChannel.transactionCapacity = 1000
 
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = memoryChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs:/user/flume/tweets/
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true
```

Comment: What exception do you see?

Comment: @werner ERROR hdfs.HDFSEventSink: process failed
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is supposed to be overridden by subclasses.

Comment: Are you probably seeing this [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-9845)?

Comment: @werner I'm not quite understanding. I am using hadoop v1

Comment: In the question, you said Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.2.1, though... By the way, that's really old, and says nothing about the Flume version, which may not even have Twitter source... Please post the **full** stacktrace